# CSS Layout issues - need 100% width on 2 divs screenshot and fiddle included

Tags: css

Im trying to create a new master page without using a table and its causing me a headache.

Its very nearly there, I just need to make the 'Messages' and 'Content' divs full width so the 'Menu' div, plus the 'Messages' and 'Content' div are the same width (100% of the screen) as the 'Top' div.

I have set up a jsFiddle, can anyone give me some pointers?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1HO5.png

http://jsfiddle.net/CJRv5/

Im happy to change HTML a bit but the following must be considered:

menu is 130px wide, the rest of the content must fill remaining window width - no 960 grid!

Comment: Have you considered using 960 grid system to accomplish your layout ? Take a look at it, it's by far the best way to do layouts

Comment: you need to specify the width explicitly in either px or %. Using % is more flexible but if you want margins and/or padding you'll need to use containers

Comment: Yes, I have considered it, but unfortunately 960 pixels is not enough for alot of the pages in this system, im just updating the master page to not use tables at the moment so I need to maintain the extra real estate on larger monitors

Comment: p.s. agree with @EvilP, use 960 grid

Comment: @scibuff - if i specify width for the messages and content div they appear below the menu

Comment: I cleaned up your markup and CSS, hope you don't mind: http://jsfiddle.net/CJRv5/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest (unintuitive) way, just change

```
    #divMasterSubContainer
    {
        float: left;
        ...
```

to

```
    #divMasterSubContainer
    {
       overflow:hidden;
       ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CJRv5/2/
Ref http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/

Comment: aha! that looks perfect, Ill need to try it out to make sure page content is not hidden buts thats certainly what i was looking for.

Comment: hmm, seems to cause all of my content pages to not show, thing im going to have to use a table for the time being - spent too much time on this already!

Answer (score 0):

^ you need to make sure that the width of menu + width of messages/content is not more than the width of the container in which they reside. Do something like this

```
div { border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;{

#content { 
    width: 100%;
}
.clear-both { clear: both; }
.float-left { float: left; }
#menu { width: 20%; }
#main { width: 80%; }

<div id="content">
    <div id="menu" class="float-left">
        <p>menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="float-left">
        <div id="message"><p>messages</p></div>
        <div id="content"><p>content</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear-both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, thats almost what i want. Is there no way of doing it without a table? I need a 130px menu, and the rest to fill whats left. We all use dual 24" monitors here any any % would be too much screen used for the menu, on smaller monitors it would then not be enough if I was to reduce the %

Comment: @WraitNath - You can use [`max-width`](http://jsfiddle.net/CJRv5/5/). Older browsers may not support this very well, though.